# What is the correct way to create a single-instance WPF application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mutex

Using C# and WPF under .NET (rather than [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) or console), what is the correct way to create an application that can only be run as a single instance?

I know it has something to do with some mythical thing called a mutex, rarely can I find someone that bothers to stop and explain what one of these are.

The code needs to also inform the already-running instance that the user tried to start a second one, and maybe also pass any command-line arguments if any existed.

Comment: Doesn't the CLR automatically release any unreleased mutexes when the application terminates anyway?

Comment: @Cocowalla: the finalizer should dispose the unmanaged mutexes unless it can't know if the mutex was created by the managed app or attached to an existing one.

Comment: Having only one instance of your app is reasonable. But passing arguments to an already existing app appears to me a bit silly. I can't see any reason to do so. If you associate an app with file extension, you should open as many app as user want to open documents. That's the standard behavior which every users would expect.

Comment: Just want to make correction about my previous state. Passing arguments to an existing app means that you want to do an MDI (multi document interface). I thought that MDI was a way that Microsoft was pushing out (Word and Excel are now SDI). But I realize that Chrome and IE are both MDI. Perharps we are in years where MDI is back ??? (But I still prefer SDI over MDI)

Comment: @Cocowalla The CLR does not manage native resources. However, if a process terminates, all handles are freed by the system (the OS, not the CLR).

Comment: I prefer the answer by @huseyint. It uses Microsoft's own 'SingleInstance.cs' class, so you don't have to worry about Mutexes and IntPtrs. Also, no dependency on VisualBasic (yuk). See http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20871/wpf-single-instance-best-practices/25667#25667 for more...

Comment: I use SingleInstanceApp nuget. https://www.nuget.org/packages/SingleInstanceApp/ Works perfect. Does not require Microsoft.VisualBasic reference. Does not depend on app version (it does in Microsoft.VisualBasic). The app is identified by unique string only.

Answer (score 612, accepted):

Here is a very good [article](http://sanity-free.org/143/csharp_dotnet_single_instance_application.html) regarding the Mutex solution.  The approach described by the article is advantageous for two reasons.

First, it does not require a dependency on the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly.  If my project already had a dependency on that assembly, I would probably advocate using the approach [shown in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19326/3195477).  But as it is, I do not use the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly, and I'd rather not add an unnecessary dependency to my project.

Second, the article shows how to bring the existing instance of the application to the foreground when the user tries to start another instance.  That's a very nice touch that the other Mutex solutions described here do not address.

---

#### UPDATE

As of 8/1/2014, the article I linked to above is still active, but the blog hasn't been updated in a while.  That makes me worry that eventually it might disappear, and with it, the advocated solution.  I'm reproducing the content of the article here for posterity.  The words belong solely to the blog owner at [Sanity Free Coding](http://sanity-free.org/).

> Today I wanted to refactor some code that prohibited my application
>   from running multiple instances of itself.
>
> Previously I had use [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) to search for an
>   instance of my myapp.exe in the process list. While this works, it
>   brings on a lot of overhead, and I wanted something cleaner.
>
> Knowing that I could use a mutex for this (but never having done it
>   before) I set out to cut down my code and simplify my life.
>
> In the class of my application main I created a static named [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
static class Program
{
    static Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "{8F6F0AC4-B9A1-45fd-A8CF-72F04E6BDE8F}");
    [STAThread]
    ...
}
```

> Having a named mutex allows us to stack synchronization across
>   multiple threads and processes which is just the magic I'm looking
>   for.
>
> [Mutex.WaitOne](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd(v=vs.110).aspx) has an overload that specifies an amount of time for us
>   to wait. Since we're not actually wanting to synchronizing our code
>   (more just check if it is currently in use) we use the overload with
>   two parameters: [Mutex.WaitOne(Timespan timeout, bool exitContext)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85bbbxt9(v=vs.110).aspx).
>   Wait one returns true if it is able to enter, and false if it wasn't.
>   In this case, we don't want to wait at all; If our mutex is being
>   used, skip it, and move on, so we pass in TimeSpan.Zero (wait 0
>   milliseconds), and set the exitContext to true so we can exit the
>   synchronization context before we try to aquire a lock on it. Using
>   this, we wrap our Application.Run code inside something like this:

```
static class Program
{
    static Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "{8F6F0AC4-B9A1-45fd-A8CF-72F04E6BDE8F}");
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        if(mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true)) {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        } else {
            MessageBox.Show("only one instance at a time");
        }
    }
}
```

> So, if our app is running, WaitOne will return false, and we'll get a
>   message box.
>
> Instead of showing a message box, I opted to utilize a little Win32 to
>   notify my running instance that someone forgot that it was already
>   running (by bringing itself to the top of all the other windows). To
>   achieve this I used [PostMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944(v=vs.85).aspx) to broadcast a custom message to every
>   window (the custom message was registered with [RegisterWindowMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644947(v=vs.85).aspx)
>   by my running application, which means only my application knows what
>   it is) then my second instance exits. The running application instance
>   would receive that notification and process it. In order to do that, I
>   overrode [WndProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.wndproc(v=vs.110).aspx) in my main form and listened for my custom
>   notification. When I received that notification I set the form's
>   TopMost property to true to bring it up on top.
>
> Here is what I ended up with:
>
> - Program.cs

```
static class Program
{
    static Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "{8F6F0AC4-B9A1-45fd-A8CF-72F04E6BDE8F}");
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        if(mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true)) {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        } else {
            // send our Win32 message to make the currently running instance
            // jump on top of all the other windows
            NativeMethods.PostMessage(
                (IntPtr)NativeMethods.HWND_BROADCAST,
                NativeMethods.WM_SHOWME,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
}
```

> - NativeMethods.cs

```
// this class just wraps some Win32 stuff that we're going to use
internal class NativeMethods
{
    public const int HWND_BROADCAST = 0xffff;
    public static readonly int WM_SHOWME = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_SHOWME");
    [DllImport("user32")]
    public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam);
    [DllImport("user32")]
    public static extern int RegisterWindowMessage(string message);
}
```

> - Form1.cs (front side partial)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if(m.Msg == NativeMethods.WM_SHOWME) {
            ShowMe();
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
    private void ShowMe()
    {
        if(WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized) {
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
        // get our current "TopMost" value (ours will always be false though)
        bool top = TopMost;
        // make our form jump to the top of everything
        TopMost = true;
        // set it back to whatever it was
        TopMost = top;
    }
}
```

Comment: On the basis that this answer uses less code and less libraries and provides the raise to top functionality, I'm going to make this the new accepted answer. If anyone knows a more correct way to bring the form to the top using API's, feel free to add that.

Comment: Not sure I understand - why use Native Messages?  That's what events are for... (if it's for the decoupling, you should really be using cab or [EventBroker](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/EventBroker.aspx)...)

Comment: @BlueRaja, you start up the first app instance.  When you start up the second app instance, it detects that another instance is already running and prepares to shutdown.  Before doing so, it sends a "SHOWME" native message to the first instance, which brings the first instance to the top.  Events in .NET don't allow cross-process communication, which is why the native message is used.

Comment: Is there a way to pass the command lines from the other instance, maybe?

Comment: @matt david - don't worry about 'shipping' Microsoft.VisualBasic - it is already in the GAC. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226517/is-the-microsoft-visualbasic-namespace-true-net-code

Comment: @Simon_Weaver, the issue is not whether it is in the GAC or not, but the fact that it is delivered with the .NET Framework.  I was not aware of that.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: @matt - i just wish they'd named the damn thing something else! i've just started using that component myself and it works quite well (my users will never know i stooped so low as to include a VB namespace - heh). its very convenient to be able to pass parameters and/or have the dormant application bring itself to the front without having to mess with any communication code yourself

Comment: @Matt: How can we choose the name for the Mutex? In the sample it is `{8F6F0AC4-B9A1-45fd-A8CF-72F04E6BDE8F}` Where is it from :) ?

Comment: @Nam, the `Mutex` constructor simply requires a string, so you could supply any string name you want, e.g., "This Is My Mutex".  Because a 'Mutex' is a system object that is available to other processes, you typically want the name to be unique so it doesn't clash with other 'Mutex' names on the same system.  In the article, the cryptic-looking string is a 'Guid'.  You can generate this programmatically by calling `System.Guid.NewGuid()`.  In the case of the article, the user probably generated it via Visual Studio as shown here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241442(VS.80).aspx

Comment: @Matt Davis, you CANNOT use System.Guid.NewGuid() because each time you get different GUID, and in effect each instance of your program will claim it is single instance. You have to use some token, common to ALL instances, defined at compile time. VS generated GUID is the way.

Comment: @macias, I never said that you would call `System.Guid.NewGuid()` and then pass the result to the Mutex.  That would obviously be wrong as you have deftly pointed out.  The question was where the string came from.  I was simply saying that a GUID could be generated programmatically or using Visual Studio.

Comment: Does the mutex approach assume that the same user is attempting to start the application again? Certainly bringing "the existing instance of the application to the foreground" does not make sense after a 'switch user'

Comment: The question asked for an approach for WPF, not WinForms as the answer proposes. I used [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5484315/433718) for a WPF application. It's also posted as answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2932076/433718

Comment: @OneWorld, this solution is agnostic to the UI framework.  The example shows how to do it using WinForms, but it'd be just as easy to use in WPF.  The solution you posted uses .NET Remoting, a legacy technology that Microsoft retains for backward compatibility only.  That's hardly a solution I would endorse.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @MattDavis Didn't know about that. Good that we clarified that. The autor Arik Poznanski seemed to express high confidence that his approach has done it right. And several people said this is a "novice" approach, since it was from 2010. I did not use your solution because I could not find a method `protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)`

Comment: @OneWorld, see the answers here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624367/how-to-handle-wndproc-messages-in-wpf

Comment: While this post is old, answering to @gyurisc might help future explorers. This answer works well for implementing single instance app. We have similar solution working fine for sometime with our customer base. To pass arguments to already running instance, we can simply write the arguments to a file and place it in the AppData for the app. Which can be picked up by running app. The name of the file could be DatetTime.Ticks to ensure most recent args are picked up, just in case!

Comment: From some reason, if you set `this.ShowInTaskbar = false` this method won't work. It just won't receive the WM_SHOWME message in WndProc method.

Comment: Instead of setting `TopMost` there and back again, one can call simply `Activate();`

Comment: Instead of using the old Native Message system, you can use `NamedPipe` with `NamedPipeClientStream` and `NamePipeServerStream`. It's more modern and allow you to pass any complementary informations (like a message requiring the living instance to quit). I don't know the performance cost of this method but I have used it without seeing problems. For my use, I just call `npServer.WaitForConnection()` and then immediately close the stream to make a new NamedPipeServerStream and wait other notifications. This in a infinite loop.

Comment: This answers doesn't describe how to pass command line arguments to another instance. It should not be the accepter answer.

Comment: How is this code affected by multiple users running same app in different sessions? Is the code "per session"? Because I only want to limit one app per session - not the whole computer.

Comment: @serializer To limit one app per the whole computer you need "Global\" prefix to mutex name. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx

Comment: @Serg I think I was looking for "Local\" as  I want to limit per session, not computer. Thanks anyway!

Comment: This answer combined with http://stackoverflow.com/a/9330103/2358659 have me really slick solution for WPF application, as I couldn't get my head around WndProc with WPF.

Comment: Consider catching the `AbandonedMutexException` when calling `WaitOne`.  This would indicate that the previous instance of the application was ended abruptly without releasing the mutex.  You probably don't care since it is not currently running anymore and can go ahead and start a new instance.

Comment: This will use the Assembly GUID.
```static Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, ((GuidAttribute)Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GuidAttribute), true)[0]).Value);```  Also you can just do it on your main form, and don't need to release the mutex, the finalizer will do it for you when program is ended.

Comment: Could you add a note about the Mutex? Looks like 120+ programs are using the same Mutex now: https://github.com/search?q=8F6F0AC4-B9A1-45fd-A8CF-72F04E6BDE8F&type=Code

Comment: @dustytrash lol.  I had no idea.  The solution above uses what is called a named mutex, which makes it available at the system level.  This is important so that the first process and any subsequent processes can access it.  The only requirement is that it be a string.  In the example above, I generated a Guid using Visual Studio's Guid generator (Tools|Create Guid) so that the string would be unique for the application.  You could generate and use another Guid, or use you own unique string.  You just don't want it to cause collisions with other named Mutexes on the system.  HTH

Comment: @MattDavis The issue is if people are copying & pasting your Mutex without really understanding it. Anyone who uses this code should generate their own Mutex the same way you did, that way it's unique and not used in other programs on the same system

Comment: @MattDavis Could the answer generate a random string?

Comment: @Tomas Zubiri  As I understand your question, no.  As each instance of the application is opened, it needs to be able to locate the Mutex created by the very first application instance.  Thus, for this solution to work, the name has to be fixed. If each instance generated a random string and then looked up a Mutex on that random string, each application instance would create a new Mutex, and all of them would remain open. Now, if you meant can the name of the Mutex be a random string as opposed to a Guid-based string, yes.  You could use, for example, "MyRandomlyNamedMutex."

Comment: Ah I see, maybe the string could have a project-specific string prepended to it? Kind of like a namespace.

Comment: @Tomas Zubiri  It can be any string you want it to be.  It just needs to be fixed so that every instance of the application can locate the named Mutex.  If the string is changing from application instance to application instance, this solution won't work because each application instance will be looking for a unique Mutex, where the solution is based on a single Mutex across all application instances.

Comment: Yep, I get it. I was suggesting the answer could have the project specific string preprended to it, in order to avoid copy-paste bugs.

Comment: @TomasZubiri If people are copying and pasting code from SO without reading and understanding it, that's their problem, not Matt's.

Comment: As already mentioned by Malgaur, this answer throws an `AbandonedMutexException` on `WaitOne`. [The answer of Legends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47849014/1951524) is also using a `Mutex` but does not throw an Exception.

Comment: On WPF applications you can solve it without using waitone (which can throw an exception). See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59079638/4491768

Comment: protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) works only in run as administrator mode

Comment: @MattDavis, but how can i pass the commandline arguments to the instances app?

Answer (score 123):

You could use the Mutex class, but you will soon find out that you will need to implement the code to pass the arguments and such yourself.  Well, I learned a trick when programming in WinForms when I read [Chris Sell's book](http://sellsbrothers.com/wfbook/).  This trick uses logic that is already available to us in the framework.  I don't know about you, but when I learn about stuff I can reuse in the framework, that is usually the route I take instead of reinventing the wheel.  Unless of course it doesn't do everything I want.

When I got into WPF, I came up with a way to use that same code, but in a WPF application.  This solution should meet your needs based off your question.

First, we need to create our application class.  In this class we are going override the OnStartup event and create a method called Activate, which will be used later.

```
public class SingleInstanceApplication : System.Windows.Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        // Call the OnStartup event on our base class
        base.OnStartup(e);

        // Create our MainWindow and show it
        MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
        window.Show();
    }

    public void Activate()
    {
        // Reactivate the main window
        MainWindow.Activate();
    }
}
```

Second, we will need to create a class that can manage our instances.  Before we go through that, we are actually going to reuse some code that is in the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly.  Since, I am using C# in this example, I had to make a reference to the assembly.  If you are using VB.NET, you don't have to do anything.  The class we are going to use is WindowsFormsApplicationBase and inherit our instance manager off of it and then leverage properties and events to handle the single instancing.

```
public class SingleInstanceManager : Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase
{
    private SingleInstanceApplication _application;
    private System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<string> _commandLine;

    public SingleInstanceManager()
    {
        IsSingleInstance = true;
    }

    protected override bool OnStartup(Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        // First time _application is launched
        _commandLine = eventArgs.CommandLine;
        _application = new SingleInstanceApplication();
        _application.Run();
        return false;
    }

    protected override void OnStartupNextInstance(StartupNextInstanceEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        // Subsequent launches
        base.OnStartupNextInstance(eventArgs);
        _commandLine = eventArgs.CommandLine;
        _application.Activate();
    }
}
```

Basically, we are using the VB bits to detect single instance's and process accordingly.  OnStartup will be fired when the first instance loads.  OnStartupNextInstance is fired when the application is re-run again.  As you can see, I can get to what was passed on the command line through the event arguments.  I set the value to an instance field.  You could parse the command line here, or you could pass it to your application through the constructor and the call to the Activate method.

Third, it's time to create our EntryPoint.  Instead of newing up the application like you would normally do, we are going to take advantage of our SingleInstanceManager.

```
public class EntryPoint
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SingleInstanceManager manager = new SingleInstanceManager();
        manager.Run(args);
    }
}
```

Well, I hope you are able to follow everything and be able use this implementation and make it your own.

Comment: This is the way we do it and I've never been too happy about it because of the dependency on WinForms.

Comment: I'd stick with the mutex solution because it has nothing to do with forms.

Comment: I've used this because I had issues with other approaches, but I'm fairly sure it uses remoting under the hood. My app has had two related issues - some customers say it tries to phone home even though they've told it not to. When they look more carefully, the connection is to localhost. Still, they don't initially know that. Also, I can't use remoting for a different purpose (I think?) because it's already being used for this. When I tried the mutex approach, I could then use remoting again.

Comment: Forgive me, but unless I a missing something, you avoided writing 3 lines of code and instead you re-used framework just to write pretty heavy code to do it. So where are the savings?

Comment: it's possible do it in winforms?

Comment: If you don't call InitializeComponent() on the application instance, you won't be able to resolve resources...

_application = new SingleInstanceApplication();
_application.InitializeComponent();
_application.Run();

Comment: How to use it in WinForms!?

Comment: I am down voting it because of its dependency on Winforms.

Comment: This does not work with custom uri. It just opens another app and does nothing.

Comment: This approach is described in Microsoft official WPF examples: https://github.com/microsoft/WPF-Samples/tree/master/Application%20Management/SingleInstanceDetection
I don't understand the hate about WinForms dependency, as the author mentioned, it's about reusing framework components and not to reinvent the wheel. I personally don't think self customized mutex solution is easier to maintain than ready made components within the framework. WinForm comes together with framework, not extra dependency. As for performance, measures are needed.

Answer (score 96):

From [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.html#_MutexSingleAppInstance).

A common use for a cross-process Mutex is to ensure that only instance of a program can run at a time. Here's how it's done:

```
class OneAtATimePlease {

  // Use a name unique to the application (eg include your company URL)
  static Mutex mutex = new Mutex (false, "oreilly.com OneAtATimeDemo");

  static void Main()
  {
    // Wait 5 seconds if contended – in case another instance
    // of the program is in the process of shutting down.
    if (!mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds (5), false))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Another instance of the app is running. Bye!");
        return;
    }

    try
    {    
        Console.WriteLine("Running - press Enter to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    finally
    {
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }    
  }    
}
```

A good feature of Mutex is that if the application terminates without ReleaseMutex first being called, the CLR will release the Mutex automatically.

Comment: I've got to say, I like this answer a lot more than the accepted one simply due to the fact that it isn't dependent on WinForms.  Personally most of my development has been moving to WPF and I don't want to have to pull in WinForm libraries for something like this.

Comment: Of course, to be a full answer, you have to also describe passing the arguments to the other instance :)

Comment: @Jason, good, thanks! But I prefer not passing any timeout. It is so much subjective and depends on so many variables. If you ever want to enable another app to start, just release your mutex quicker.. for example as soon as the user confirm close

Comment: @EricOuellet: Just about every program that has tabs does this - Photoshop, Sublime Text, Chrome .... If you have a good reason to have a "master" process (say you have a in-proc DB for settings) you might want to have it show UI as if it were a new process too.

Comment: @Simon, you are right. I just question myself about a very old thing... MDI vs SDI (Multi documentinterface vs Single document interface). When you talk about tabs, you refer to MDI. In 1998, a Microsoft book suggests to eliminate every MDI app. Microsoft switched Word, Excel... to SDI which I think it is simplier and better. I understand that Chrome and others (now IE) want back to MDI. I personnaly (based on nothing / personal feelings) that it is still better to open a new app when file assoc is selected. But I understand better the question asked now. Thanks !

Comment: @EricOuellet: The problems with MDI were probably far more about having windows within windows than tabs being confusing, and there's a strong push to all tabs being pulled out into their own top-level window, mitigating it. These are all UI concerns though, which shouldn't have any connection to how you split up your processes (multiple processes can be contained in the same window, and vice-versa).

Comment: Any idea where to to put this into a .NET 6 WPF application?

Answer (score 68):

MSDN actually has a sample application for both C# and VB to do exactly this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771662(v=VS.90).aspx

> The most common and reliable technique
>   for developing single-instance
>   detection is to use the Microsoft .NET
>   Framework remoting infrastructure
>   (System.Remoting). The Microsoft .NET
>   Framework (version 2.0) includes a
>   type, WindowsFormsApplicationBase,
>   which encapsulates the required
>   remoting functionality. To incorporate
>   this type into a WPF application, a
>   type needs to derive from it, and be
>   used as a shim between the application
>   static entry point method, Main, and
>   the WPF application's Application
>   type. The shim detects when an
>   application is first launched, and
>   when subsequent launches are
>   attempted, and yields control the WPF
>   Application type to determine how to
>   process the launches.

- For C# people just take a deep breath and forget about  the whole 'I don't wanna include VisualBasic DLL'. Because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226517/is-the-microsoft-visualbasic-namespace-true-net-code) and what [Scott Hanselman says](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode31SingleInstanceWinFormsAndMicrosoftVisualBasicdll.aspx) and the fact that this pretty much is the cleanest solution to the problem and is designed by people who know a lot more about the framework than you do.
- From a usability standpoint the fact is if your user is loading an application and it is already open and you're giving them an error message like `'Another instance of the app is running. Bye'` then they're not gonna be a very happy user. You simply MUST (in a GUI application) switch to that application and pass in the arguments provided - or if command line parameters have no meaning then you must pop up the application which may have been minimized.

The framework already has support for this - its just that some idiot named the DLL `Microsoft.VisualBasic` and it didn't get put into `Microsoft.ApplicationUtils` or something like that. Get over it - or open up Reflector.

Tip: If you use this approach exactly as is, and you already have an App.xaml with resources etc. you'll want to [take a look at this too](http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2008/09/how_to_write_custom_main_metho.html).

Comment: Thank you for including the 'take a look at this too' link.  That's exactly what I needed.  By the way, solution #3 in your link is the best one.

Comment: I am also an advocate of delegating to the framework and specially designed libraries where possible.

Answer (score 27):

This code should go to the main method. Look at [here](http://joyfulwpf.blogspot.com/2009/05/where-is-main-method-in-my-wpf.html) for more information about the main method in WPF.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern Boolean ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow);

private const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;

static void Main() 
{
    Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    var runningProcess = (from process in Process.GetProcesses()
                          where
                            process.Id != currentProcess.Id &&
                            process.ProcessName.Equals(
                              currentProcess.ProcessName,
                              StringComparison.Ordinal)
                          select process).FirstOrDefault();
    if (runningProcess != null)
    {
        ShowWindow(runningProcess.MainWindowHandle, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
       return; 
    }
}
```

**Method 2**

```
static void Main()
{
    string procName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
    // get the list of all processes by that name

    Process[] processes=Process.GetProcessesByName(procName);

    if (processes.Length > 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(procName + " already running");  
        return;
    } 
    else
    {
        // Application.Run(...);
    }
}
```

**Note :** Above methods assumes your process/application has a unique name. Because it uses process name to find if any existing processors. So, if your application has a very common name (ie: Notepad), above approach won't work.

Comment: Also, this won't work if there's any other program running on your computer with the same name. `ProcessName` returns the executable file name minus the `exe`. If you make an application called "Notepad", and the windows notepad is running, it'll detect it as your application running.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I have found so many similar questions and the answers were always so elaborate and/or confusing I've found them useless. This one (Method #1) is straightforward, clear and most of all it actually helped me make my code run.

Answer (score 20):

Well, I have a disposable Class for this that works easily for most use cases:

Use it like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    using (SingleInstanceMutex sim = new SingleInstanceMutex())
    {
        if (sim.IsOtherInstanceRunning)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        // Initialize program here.
    }
}
```

Here it is:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a <see cref="SingleInstanceMutex"/> class.
/// </summary>
public partial class SingleInstanceMutex : IDisposable
{
    #region Fields

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicator whether another instance of this application is running or not.
    /// </summary>
    private bool isNoOtherInstanceRunning;

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="Mutex"/> used to ask for other instances of this application.
    /// </summary>
    private Mutex singleInstanceMutex = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// An indicator whether this object is beeing actively disposed or not.
    /// </summary>
    private bool disposed;

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SingleInstanceMutex"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public SingleInstanceMutex()
    {
        this.singleInstanceMutex = new Mutex(true, Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().FullName, out this.isNoOtherInstanceRunning);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an indicator whether another instance of the application is running or not.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsOtherInstanceRunning
    {
        get
        {
            return !this.isNoOtherInstanceRunning;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Closes the <see cref="SingleInstanceMutex"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public void Close()
    {
        this.ThrowIfDisposed();
        this.singleInstanceMutex.Close();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            /* Release unmanaged ressources */

            if (disposing)
            {
                /* Release managed ressources */
                this.Close();
            }

            this.disposed = true;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Throws an exception if something is tried to be done with an already disposed object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// All public methods of the class must first call this.
    /// </remarks>
    public void ThrowIfDisposed()
    {
        if (this.disposed)
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.GetType().Name);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: this one was pretty easy to get working. It would not close the second application until I changed Application.Exit(); to a simple return; but other than that its great. Although i admit I am going to look at the previous solution closer since it uses an interface.
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2010/05/28/wpf-single-instance-application.aspx

Answer (score 15):

A new one that uses Mutex and IPC stuff, and also passes any command line arguments to the running instance, is *[WPF Single Instance Application](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2010/05/28/wpf-single-instance-application.aspx)*.

Comment: I use this with great success. If you incorporate NamedPipes with this, you can also pass command-line arguments to the original application. The class, 'SingleInstance.cs', was written by Microsoft. I have added another link to a more readable version of Arik Poznanski's blog on CodeProject.

Comment: Link is now broken.

Comment: Try this one (same date, same author's first name, so presumably same article): https://www.codeproject.com/articles/84270/wpf-single-instance-application

Comment: Copy can be found here. https://gist.github.com/karthikeyan1241997/f1490a40bcb0551b1a9110cde760c128

Answer (score 13):

The code [C# .NET Single Instance Application](http://sanity-free.org/143/csharp_dotnet_single_instance_application.html) that is the reference for the marked answer is a great start.

However, I found it doesn't handle very well the cases when the instance that already exist has a modal dialog open, whether that dialog is a managed one (like another Form such as an about box), or an unmanaged one (like the OpenFileDialog even when using the standard .NET class). With the original code, the main form is activated, but the modal one stays unactive, which looks strange, plus the user must click on it to keep using the app.

So, I have create a SingleInstance utility class to handle all this quite automatically for Winforms and WPF applications.

**Winforms**:

1) modify the Program class like this:

```
static class Program
{
    public static readonly SingleInstance Singleton = new SingleInstance(typeof(Program).FullName);

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // NOTE: if this always return false, close & restart Visual Studio
        // this is probably due to the vshost.exe thing
        Singleton.RunFirstInstance(() =>
        {
            SingleInstanceMain(args);
        });
    }

    public static void SingleInstanceMain(string[] args)
    {
        // standard code that was in Main now goes here
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

2) modify the main window class like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        // if needed, the singleton will restore this window
        Program.Singleton.OnWndProc(this, m, true);

        // TODO: handle specific messages here if needed
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

**WPF:**

1) modify the App page like this (and make sure you set its build action to page to be able to redefine the Main method):

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static readonly SingleInstance Singleton = new SingleInstance(typeof(App).FullName);

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // NOTE: if this always return false, close & restart Visual Studio
        // this is probably due to the vshost.exe thing
        Singleton.RunFirstInstance(() =>
        {
            SingleInstanceMain(args);
        });
    }

    public static void SingleInstanceMain(string[] args)
    {
        // standard code that was in Main now goes here
        App app = new App();
        app.InitializeComponent();
        app.Run();
    }
}
```

2) modify the main window class like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private HwndSource _source;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
        _source = (HwndSource)PresentationSource.FromVisual(this);
        _source.AddHook(HwndSourceHook);
    }

    protected virtual IntPtr HwndSourceHook(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        // if needed, the singleton will restore this window
        App.Singleton.OnWndProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam, true, true);

        // TODO: handle other specific message
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
```

And here is the utility class:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace SingleInstanceUtilities
{
    public sealed class SingleInstance
    {
        private const int HWND_BROADCAST = 0xFFFF;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern int RegisterWindowMessage(string message);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        public SingleInstance(string uniqueName)
        {
            if (uniqueName == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("uniqueName");

            Mutex = new Mutex(true, uniqueName);
            Message = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_" + uniqueName);
        }

        public Mutex Mutex { get; private set; }
        public int Message { get; private set; }

        public void RunFirstInstance(Action action)
        {
            RunFirstInstance(action, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        }

        // NOTE: if this always return false, close & restart Visual Studio
        // this is probably due to the vshost.exe thing
        public void RunFirstInstance(Action action, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (action == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("action");

            if (WaitForMutext(wParam, lParam))
            {
                try
                {
                    action();
                }
                finally
                {
                    ReleaseMutex();
                }
            }
        }

        public static void ActivateWindow(IntPtr hwnd)
        {
            if (hwnd == IntPtr.Zero)
                return;

            FormUtilities.ActivateWindow(FormUtilities.GetModalWindow(hwnd));
        }

        public void OnWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int m, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, bool restorePlacement, bool activate)
        {
            if (m == Message)
            {
                if (restorePlacement)
                {
                    WindowPlacement placement = WindowPlacement.GetPlacement(hwnd, false);
                    if (placement.IsValid && placement.IsMinimized)
                    {
                        const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;
                        placement.ShowCmd = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
                        placement.SetPlacement(hwnd);
                    }
                }

                if (activate)
                {
                    SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
                    FormUtilities.ActivateWindow(FormUtilities.GetModalWindow(hwnd));
                }
            }
        }

#if WINFORMS // define this for Winforms apps
        public void OnWndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Form form, int m, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, bool activate)
        {
            if (form == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("form");

            if (m == Message)
            {
                if (activate)
                {
                    if (form.WindowState == System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Minimized)
                    {
                        form.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Normal;
                    }

                    form.Activate();
                    FormUtilities.ActivateWindow(FormUtilities.GetModalWindow(form.Handle));
                }
            }
        }

        public void OnWndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Form form, System.Windows.Forms.Message m, bool activate)
        {
            if (form == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("form");

            OnWndProc(form, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam, activate);
        }
#endif

        public void ReleaseMutex()
        {
            Mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }

        public bool WaitForMutext(bool force, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            bool b = PrivateWaitForMutext(force);
            if (!b)
            {
                PostMessage((IntPtr)HWND_BROADCAST, Message, wParam, lParam);
            }
            return b;
        }

        public bool WaitForMutext(IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            return WaitForMutext(false, wParam, lParam);
        }

        private bool PrivateWaitForMutext(bool force)
        {
            if (force)
                return true;

            try
            {
                return Mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true);
            }
            catch (AbandonedMutexException)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    // NOTE: don't add any field or public get/set property, as this must exactly map to Windows' WINDOWPLACEMENT structure
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct WindowPlacement
    {
        public int Length { get; set; }
        public int Flags { get; set; }
        public int ShowCmd { get; set; }
        public int MinPositionX { get; set; }
        public int MinPositionY { get; set; }
        public int MaxPositionX { get; set; }
        public int MaxPositionY { get; set; }
        public int NormalPositionLeft { get; set; }
        public int NormalPositionTop { get; set; }
        public int NormalPositionRight { get; set; }
        public int NormalPositionBottom { get; set; }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool SetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, ref WindowPlacement lpwndpl);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool GetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, ref WindowPlacement lpwndpl);

        private const int SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2;

        public bool IsMinimized
        {
            get
            {
                return ShowCmd == SW_SHOWMINIMIZED;
            }
        }

        public bool IsValid
        {
            get
            {
                return Length == Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WindowPlacement));
            }
        }

        public void SetPlacement(IntPtr windowHandle)
        {
            SetWindowPlacement(windowHandle, ref this);
        }

        public static WindowPlacement GetPlacement(IntPtr windowHandle, bool throwOnError)
        {
            WindowPlacement placement = new WindowPlacement();
            if (windowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                return placement;

            placement.Length = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WindowPlacement));
            if (!GetWindowPlacement(windowHandle, ref placement))
            {
                if (throwOnError)
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                return new WindowPlacement();
            }
            return placement;
        }
    }

    public static class FormUtilities
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int uCmd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetActiveWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetCurrentThreadId();

        private delegate bool EnumChildrenCallback(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool EnumThreadWindows(int dwThreadId, EnumChildrenCallback lpEnumFunc, IntPtr lParam);

        private class ModalWindowUtil
        {
            private const int GW_OWNER = 4;
            private int _maxOwnershipLevel;
            private IntPtr _maxOwnershipHandle;

            private bool EnumChildren(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lParam)
            {
                int level = 1;
                if (IsWindowVisible(hwnd) && IsOwned(lParam, hwnd, ref level))
                {
                    if (level > _maxOwnershipLevel)
                    {
                        _maxOwnershipHandle = hwnd;
                        _maxOwnershipLevel = level;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

            private static bool IsOwned(IntPtr owner, IntPtr hwnd, ref int level)
            {
                IntPtr o = GetWindow(hwnd, GW_OWNER);
                if (o == IntPtr.Zero)
                    return false;

                if (o == owner)
                    return true;

                level++;
                return IsOwned(owner, o, ref level);
            }

            public static void ActivateWindow(IntPtr hwnd)
            {
                if (hwnd != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    SetActiveWindow(hwnd);
                }
            }

            public static IntPtr GetModalWindow(IntPtr owner)
            {
                ModalWindowUtil util = new ModalWindowUtil();
                EnumThreadWindows(GetCurrentThreadId(), util.EnumChildren, owner);
                return util._maxOwnershipHandle; // may be IntPtr.Zero
            }
        }

        public static void ActivateWindow(IntPtr hwnd)
        {
            ModalWindowUtil.ActivateWindow(hwnd);
        }

        public static IntPtr GetModalWindow(IntPtr owner)
        {
            return ModalWindowUtil.GetModalWindow(owner);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Just some thoughts:
There are cases when requiring that only one instance of an application is not "lame" as some would have you believe. Database apps, etc. are an order of magnitude more difficult if one allows multiple instances of the app for a single user to access a database (you know, all that updating all the records that are open in multiple instances of the app on the users machine, etc.). 
First, for the "name collision thing, don't use a human readable name - use a GUID instead or, even better a GUID + the human readable name. Chances of name collision just dropped off the radar and the Mutex doesn't care. As someone pointed out, a DOS attack would suck, but if the malicious person has gone to the trouble of getting the mutex name and incorporating it into their app, you are pretty much a target anyway and will have to do MUCH more to protect yourself than just fiddle a mutex name.
Also, if one uses the variant of:
new Mutex(true, "some GUID plus Name", out AIsFirstInstance), you already have your indicator as to whether or not the Mutex is the first instance.

Answer (score 11):

Here is an example that allows you to have a single instance of an application. When any new instances load, they pass their arguments to the main instance that is running.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private static Mutex SingleMutex;
    public static uint MessageId;

    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr Result;
        IntPtr SendOk;
        Win32.COPYDATASTRUCT CopyData;
        string[] Args;
        IntPtr CopyDataMem;
        bool AllowMultipleInstances = false;

        Args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

        // TODO: Replace {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} with your application's GUID
        MessageId   = Win32.RegisterWindowMessage("{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}");
        SingleMutex = new Mutex(false, "AppName");

        if ((AllowMultipleInstances) || (!AllowMultipleInstances && SingleMutex.WaitOne(1, true)))
        {
            new Main();
        }
        else if (Args.Length > 1)
        {
            foreach (Process Proc in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                SendOk = Win32.SendMessageTimeout(Proc.MainWindowHandle, MessageId, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero,
                    Win32.SendMessageTimeoutFlags.SMTO_BLOCK | Win32.SendMessageTimeoutFlags.SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG,
                    2000, out Result);

                if (SendOk == IntPtr.Zero)
                    continue;
                if ((uint)Result != MessageId)
                    continue;

                CopyDataMem = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Win32.COPYDATASTRUCT)));

                CopyData.dwData = IntPtr.Zero;
                CopyData.cbData = Args[1].Length*2;
                CopyData.lpData = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(Args[1]);

                Marshal.StructureToPtr(CopyData, CopyDataMem, false);

                Win32.SendMessageTimeout(Proc.MainWindowHandle, Win32.WM_COPYDATA, IntPtr.Zero, CopyDataMem,
                    Win32.SendMessageTimeoutFlags.SMTO_BLOCK | Win32.SendMessageTimeoutFlags.SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG,
                    5000, out Result);

                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(CopyData.lpData);
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(CopyDataMem);
            }

            Shutdown(0);
        }
    }
}

public partial class Main : Window
{
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HwndSource Source;

        Source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
        Source.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(Window_Proc));
    }

    private IntPtr Window_Proc(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool Handled)
    {
        Win32.COPYDATASTRUCT CopyData;
        string Path;

        if (Msg == Win32.WM_COPYDATA)
        {
            CopyData = (Win32.COPYDATASTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(Win32.COPYDATASTRUCT));
            Path = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(CopyData.lpData, CopyData.cbData / 2);

            if (WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
            {
                // Restore window from tray
            }

            // Do whatever we want with information

            Activate();
            Focus();
        }

        if (Msg == App.MessageId)
        {
            Handled = true;
            return new IntPtr(App.MessageId);
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
}

public class Win32
{
    public const uint WM_COPYDATA = 0x004A;

    public struct COPYDATASTRUCT
    {
        public IntPtr dwData;
        public int    cbData;
        public IntPtr lpData;
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum SendMessageTimeoutFlags : uint
    {
        SMTO_NORMAL             = 0x0000,
        SMTO_BLOCK              = 0x0001,
        SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG        = 0x0002,
        SMTO_NOTIMEOUTIFNOTHUNG = 0x0008
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern uint RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessageTimeout(
        IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam,
        SendMessageTimeoutFlags fuFlags, uint uTimeout, out IntPtr lpdwResult);
}
```

Comment: This is a really nice example of what I what to do. Nathan, are all the args sent using this method? I have 7 or so in my app and i *think* that this code will work.

Comment: In my example, only the first argument is sent, but it can be changed so that all of them are sent.

Answer (score 8):

The following code is my WCF named pipes solution to register a single-instance application. It's nice because it also raises an event when another instance attempts to start, and receives the command line of the other instance.

It's geared toward WPF because it uses the `System.Windows.StartupEventHandler` class, but this could be easily modified.

This code requires a reference to `PresentationFramework`, and `System.ServiceModel`.

**Usage:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var applicationId = new Guid("b54f7b0d-87f9-4df9-9686-4d8fd76066dc");

        if (SingleInstanceManager.VerifySingleInstance(applicationId))
        {
            SingleInstanceManager.OtherInstanceStarted += OnOtherInstanceStarted;

            // Start the application
        }
    }

    static void OnOtherInstanceStarted(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do something in response to another instance starting up.
    }
}
```

#### Source Code:

```
/// <summary>
/// A class to use for single-instance applications.
/// </summary>
public static class SingleInstanceManager
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Raised when another instance attempts to start up.
  /// </summary>
  public static event StartupEventHandler OtherInstanceStarted;

  /// <summary>
  /// Checks to see if this instance is the first instance running on this machine.  If it is not, this method will
  /// send the main instance this instance's startup information.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="guid">The application's unique identifier.</param>
  /// <returns>True if this instance is the main instance.</returns>
  public static bool VerifySingleInstace(Guid guid)
  {
    if (!AttemptPublishService(guid))
    {
      NotifyMainInstance(guid);

      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Attempts to publish the service.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="guid">The application's unique identifier.</param>
  /// <returns>True if the service was published successfully.</returns>
  private static bool AttemptPublishService(Guid guid)
  {
    try
    {
      ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(SingleInstance));
      NetNamedPipeBinding binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None);
      serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ISingleInstance), binding, CreateAddress(guid));
      serviceHost.Open();

      return true;
    }
    catch
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Notifies the main instance that this instance is attempting to start up.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="guid">The application's unique identifier.</param>
  private static void NotifyMainInstance(Guid guid)
  {
    NetNamedPipeBinding binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None);
    EndpointAddress remoteAddress = new EndpointAddress(CreateAddress(guid));
    using (ChannelFactory<ISingleInstance> factory = new ChannelFactory<ISingleInstance>(binding, remoteAddress))
    {
      ISingleInstance singleInstance = factory.CreateChannel();
      singleInstance.NotifyMainInstance(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs());
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Creates an address to publish/contact the service at based on a globally unique identifier.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="guid">The identifier for the application.</param>
  /// <returns>The address to publish/contact the service.</returns>
  private static string CreateAddress(Guid guid)
  {
    return string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "net.pipe://localhost/{0}", guid);
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// The interface that describes the single instance service.
  /// </summary>
  [ServiceContract]
  private interface ISingleInstance
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Notifies the main instance that another instance of the application attempted to start.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args">The other instance's command-line arguments.</param>
    [OperationContract]
    void NotifyMainInstance(string[] args);
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// The implementation of the single instance service interface.
  /// </summary>
  private class SingleInstance : ISingleInstance
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Notifies the main instance that another instance of the application attempted to start.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args">The other instance's command-line arguments.</param>
    public void NotifyMainInstance(string[] args)
    {
      if (OtherInstanceStarted != null)
      {
        Type type = typeof(StartupEventArgs);
        ConstructorInfo constructor = type.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null);
        StartupEventArgs e = (StartupEventArgs)constructor.Invoke(null);
        FieldInfo argsField = type.GetField("_args", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        Debug.Assert(argsField != null);
        argsField.SetValue(e, args);

        OtherInstanceStarted(null, e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

So many answers to such a seemingly simple question.  Just to shake things up a little bit here is my solution to this problem.

Creating a Mutex can be troublesome because the JIT-er only sees you using it for a small portion of your code and wants to mark it as ready for garbage collection.  It pretty much wants to out-smart you thinking you are not going to be using that Mutex for that long.  In reality you want to hang onto this Mutex for as long as your application is running.  The best way to tell the garbage collector to leave you Mutex alone is to tell it to keep it alive though out the different generations of garage collection.  Example:

```
var m = new Mutex(...);
...
GC.KeepAlive(m);
```

I lifted the idea from this page: http://www.ai.uga.edu/~mc/SingleInstance.html

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to store a shared copy of it in the application class?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like there is a really good way to handle this:

*[WPF Single Instance Application](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2010/05/28/wpf-single-instance-application.aspx)*

This provides a class you can add that manages all the mutex and messaging cruff to simplify the your implementation to the point where it's simply trivial.

Comment: This didn't seem to bring the existing window to the foreground when I tried it.

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2932076/3220898 - and both answers are now useless because the link is dead.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the folllowing code. It is a great and simple solution to prevent multiple instances of a WPF application.

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    Process thisProc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    if (Process.GetProcessesByName(thisProc.ProcessName).Length > 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Application running");
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
        return;
    }

    var wLogin = new LoginWindow();

    if (wLogin.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        var wMain = new Main();
        wMain.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        wMain.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Not using Mutex though, simple answer:

```
System.Diagnostics;    
...
string thisprocessname = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;

if (Process.GetProcesses().Count(p => p.ProcessName == thisprocessname) > 1)
                return;
```

Put it inside the `Program.Main()`.
**Example**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Sample
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            //simple add Diagnostics namespace, and these 3 lines below 
            string thisprocessname = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
            if (Process.GetProcesses().Count(p => p.ProcessName == thisprocessname) > 1)
                return;

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Sample());
        }
    }
}
```

You can add `MessageBox.Show` to the `if`-statement and put "Application already running".
This might be helpful to someone.

Comment: If two processes start at the same time, they may both see two active processes and self-terminate.

Comment: @A.T. Yes right, this can also be helpful to apps running as Administrator or else

Comment: If you make a copy of your application and rename it, you can run the original and the copy at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

You should never use a named mutex to implement a single-instance application (or at least not for production code). Malicious code can easily DoS ([Denial of Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack)) your ass...

Comment: "You should never use a named mutex" - never say never.  If malicious code is running on my machine, I'm probably already hosed.

Comment: Actually it doesn't even have to be malicious code. It could just be a accidental name collision.

Comment: The better question is what possible reason would you want that behavior. Don't design your app as a single instance application=). I know that's a lame answer but from a design standpoint it is almost always the correct answer. Without knowing more about the app its hard to say much more.

Comment: At least under Windows, Mutexes have access control, so one one can toy with your object. As to name collisions themselves, that's why UUID/GUID's where invented.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I use. It combined process enumeration to perform switching and mutex to safeguard from "active clickers":

```
public partial class App
{
    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern int OpenIcon(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        var p = Process
           .GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
            foreach (var t in p.Where(t => t.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                OpenIcon(t.MainWindowHandle);
                SetForegroundWindow(t.MainWindowHandle);
                Current.Shutdown();
                return;
            }

            // there is a chance the user tries to click on the icon repeatedly
            // and the process cannot be discovered yet
            bool createdNew;
            var mutex = new Mutex(true, "MyAwesomeApp", 
               out createdNew);  // must be a variable, though it is unused - 
            // we just need a bit of time until the process shows up
            if (!createdNew)
            {
                Current.Shutdown();
                return;
            }

            new Bootstrapper().Run();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is Bootstrapper here?

Answer (score 4):

I found the simpler solution, similar to Dale Ragan's, but slightly modified. It does practically everything you need and based on the standard Microsoft WindowsFormsApplicationBase class.

Firstly, you create SingleInstanceController class, which you can use in all other single-instance applications, which use Windows Forms:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices;


namespace SingleInstanceController_NET
{
    public class SingleInstanceController
    : WindowsFormsApplicationBase
    {
        public delegate Form CreateMainForm();
        public delegate void StartNextInstanceDelegate(Form mainWindow);
        CreateMainForm formCreation;
        StartNextInstanceDelegate onStartNextInstance;
        public SingleInstanceController(CreateMainForm formCreation, StartNextInstanceDelegate onStartNextInstance)
        {
            // Set whether the application is single instance
            this.formCreation = formCreation;
            this.onStartNextInstance = onStartNextInstance;
            this.IsSingleInstance = true;

            this.StartupNextInstance += new StartupNextInstanceEventHandler(this_StartupNextInstance);                      
        }

        void this_StartupNextInstance(object sender, StartupNextInstanceEventArgs e)
        {
            if (onStartNextInstance != null)
            {
                onStartNextInstance(this.MainForm); // This code will be executed when the user tries to start the running program again,
                                                    // for example, by clicking on the exe file.
            }                                       // This code can determine how to re-activate the existing main window of the running application.
        }

        protected override void OnCreateMainForm()
        {
            // Instantiate your main application form
            this.MainForm = formCreation();
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            string[] commandLine = new string[0];
            base.Run(commandLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in your program as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SingleInstanceController_NET;

namespace SingleInstance
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        static Form CreateForm()
        {
            return new Form1(); // Form1 is used for the main window.
        }

        static void OnStartNextInstance(Form mainWindow) // When the user tries to restart the application again,
                                                         // the main window is activated again.
        {
            mainWindow.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);            
            SingleInstanceController controller = new SingleInstanceController(CreateForm, OnStartNextInstance);
            controller.Run();         
        }
    }
}
```

Both the program and the SingleInstanceController_NET solution should reference Microsoft.VisualBasic . If you just want to reactivate the running application as a normal window when the user tries to restart the running program, the second parameter in the SingleInstanceController can be null. In the given example, the window is maximized.

Answer (score 4):

**Update 2017-01-25.** After trying few things, I decided to go with VisualBasic.dll it is easier and works better (at least for me). I let my previous answer just as reference...

Just as reference, this is how I did without passing arguments (which I can't find any reason to do so... I mean a single app with arguments that as to be passed out from one instance to another one).
If file association is required, then an app should (per users standard expectation) be instanciated for each doc. If you have to pass args to existing app, I  think I would used vb dll.

Not passing args (just single instance app), I prefer not registering a new Window message and not override the message loop as defined in Matt Davis Solution. Although it's not a big deal to add a VisualBasic dll, but I prefer not add a new reference just to do single instance app. Also, I do prefer instanciate a new class with Main instead of calling Shutdown from App.Startup override to ensure to exit as soon as possible.

In hope that anybody will like it... or will inspire a little bit :-)

Project startup class should be set as 'SingleInstanceApp'.

```
public class SingleInstanceApp
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mutex _mutexSingleInstance = new Mutex(true, "MonitorMeSingleInstance");

        if (_mutexSingleInstance.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true))
        {
            try
            {
                var app = new App();
                app.InitializeComponent();
                app.Run();

            }
            finally
            {
                _mutexSingleInstance.ReleaseMutex();
                _mutexSingleInstance.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("One instance is already running.");

            var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name);
            {
                if (processes.Length > 1)
                {
                    foreach (var process in processes)
                    {
                        if (process.Id != Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id)
                        {
                            WindowHelper.SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

WindowHelper:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace HQ.Util.Unmanaged
{
    public class WindowHelper
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Answer (score 4):

Named-mutex-based approaches are not cross-platform because named mutexes are not global in Mono. Process-enumeration-based approaches don't have any synchronization and may result in incorrect behavior (e.g. multiple processes started at the same time may all self-terminate depending on timing). Windowing-system-based approaches are not desirable in a console application. This solution, built on top of Divin's answer, addresses all these issues:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace TestCs
{
    public class Program
    {
        // The app id must be unique. Generate a new guid for your application. 
        public static string AppId = "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef";

        // The stream is stored globally to ensure that it won't be disposed before the application terminates.
        public static FileStream UniqueInstanceStream;

        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            EnsureUniqueInstance();

            // Your code here.

            return 0;
        }

        private static void EnsureUniqueInstance()
        {
            // Note: If you want the check to be per-user, use Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData instead.
            string lockDir = Path.Combine(
                Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData),
                "UniqueInstanceApps");
            string lockPath = Path.Combine(lockDir, $"{AppId}.unique");

            Directory.CreateDirectory(lockDir);

            try
            {
                // Create the file with exclusive write access. If this fails, then another process is executing.
                UniqueInstanceStream = File.Open(lockPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);

                // Although only the line above should be sufficient, when debugging with a vshost on Visual Studio
                // (that acts as a proxy), the IO exception isn't passed to the application before a Write is executed.
                UniqueInstanceStream.Write(new byte[] { 0 }, 0, 1);
                UniqueInstanceStream.Flush();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new Exception("Another instance of the application is already running.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**[I have provided sample code for console and wpf applications below.]**

You only have to check the value of the `createdNew` variable (example below!), after you create the named Mutex instance.

The boolean `createdNew` will return **false:**

> if the Mutex instance named "YourApplicationNameHere" was already
>   created on the system somewhere

The boolean `createdNew` will return **true:**

> if this is the first Mutex named "YourApplicationNameHere" on the
>   system.

---

**Console application - Example:**

```
static Mutex m = null;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string mutexName = "YourApplicationNameHere";
    bool createdNew = false;

    try
    {
        // Initializes a new instance of the Mutex class with a Boolean value that indicates 
        // whether the calling thread should have initial ownership of the mutex, a string that is the name of the mutex, 
        // and a Boolean value that, when the method returns, indicates whether the calling thread was granted initial ownership of the mutex.

        using (m = new Mutex(true, mutexName, out createdNew))
        {
            if (!createdNew)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("instance is alreday running... shutting down !!!");
                Console.Read();
                return; // Exit the application
            }

            // Run your windows forms app here
            Console.WriteLine("Single instance app is running!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**WPF-Example:**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
static Mutex m = null;

protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{

    const string mutexName = "YourApplicationNameHere";
    bool createdNew = false;

    try
    {
        // Initializes a new instance of the Mutex class with a Boolean value that indicates 
        // whether the calling thread should have initial ownership of the mutex, a string that is the name of the mutex, 
        // and a Boolean value that, when the method returns, indicates whether the calling thread was granted initial ownership of the mutex.

        m = new Mutex(true, mutexName, out createdNew);

        if (!createdNew)
        {
            Current.Shutdown(); // Exit the application
        }

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }

    base.OnStartup(e);
}


protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
{
    if (m != null)
    {
        m.Dispose();
    }
    base.OnExit(e);
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I can't find a **short solution** here so I hope someone will like this:

**UPDATED 2018-09-20**

Put this code in your `Program.cs`:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

static void Main()
{
    Process thisProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    Process[] allProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName(thisProcess.ProcessName);
    if (allProcesses.Length > 1)
    {
        // Don't put a MessageBox in here because the user could spam this MessageBox.
        return;
    }

    // Optional code. If you don't want that someone runs your ".exe" with a different name:

    string exeName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;
    // in debug mode, don't forget that you don't use your normal .exe name.
    // Debug uses the .vshost.exe.
    if (exeName != "the name of your executable.exe") 
    {
        // You can add a MessageBox here if you want.
        // To point out to users that the name got changed and maybe what the name should be or something like that^^ 
        MessageBox.Show("The executable name should be \"the name of your executable.exe\"", 
            "Wrong executable name", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }

    // Following code is default code:
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new MainForm());
}
```

Comment: This will introduce a race condition. Must use a mutex.

Comment: there's no guarantee that if you spin up two instances at the same time that this will work. Like updating a variable from two different threads. Tricky risky business. Use the force, Luke :)

Comment: @georgiosd ah I see what you mean. Like if someone start the .exe and changes the name. Yes this would be a way to start it more times, but normaly the .exe does not work, if the name got changed.
I will update my answer^^ Thank you Luke :D for pointing that out :)

Comment: Not just that @Deniz. If you start two processes really fast, there's a chance that the process list or the method fetching them will execute while there's still only one appearing. This may be an edge case that's irrelevant to you but this being a general question...

Comment: @georgiosd Can you prove that? Because Iv'e tested it just for you hehe.
But it was not possible for me, even really "really fast" ! :P
So I can't understand why you belive in something which is just not the case and even dislike this innocent code :D

Comment: I don't have to prove it @Deniz, it's a "given" in computer science on multi-threaded systems. Google race conditions.

Comment: @georgiosd Like I already told you. I've testet to start it multiple times. There was no way it would work (at least for me). So it would be nice if you would prove it. Otherwise you're kinda unkindly :/

Answer (score 3):

I use [Mutex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex?view=netframework-4.8) in my solution for preventing multiple instances.

```
static Mutex mutex = null;
//A string that is the name of the mutex
string mutexName = @"Global\test";
//Prevent Multiple Instances of Application
bool onlyInstance = false;
mutex = new Mutex(true, mutexName, out onlyInstance);

if (!onlyInstance)
{
  MessageBox.Show("You are already running this application in your system.", "Already Running..", MessageBoxButton.OK);
  Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use mutex solution:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace OneAndOnlyOne
{
static class Program
{
    static String _mutexID = " // generate guid"
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Boolean _isNotRunning;
        using (Mutex _mutex = new Mutex(true, _mutexID, out _isNotRunning))
        {
            if (_isNotRunning)
            {
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An instance is already running.");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I added a sendMessage Method to the NativeMethods Class.

Apparently the postmessage method dosent work, if the application is not show in the taskbar, however using the sendmessage method solves this.

```
class NativeMethods
{
    public const int HWND_BROADCAST = 0xffff;
    public static readonly int WM_SHOWME = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_SHOWME");
    [DllImport("user32")]
    public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    [DllImport("user32")]
    public static extern int RegisterWindowMessage(string message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a lightweight solution I use which allows the application to bring an already existing window to the foreground without resorting to custom windows messages or blindly searching process names.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

static readonly string guid = "<Application Guid>";

static void Main()
{
    Mutex mutex = null;
    if (!CreateMutex(out mutex))
        return;

    // Application startup code.

    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(guid, null, EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
}

static bool CreateMutex(out Mutex mutex)
{
    bool createdNew = false;
    mutex = new Mutex(false, guid, out createdNew);

    if (createdNew)
    {
        Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        string value = process.Id.ToString();

        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(guid, value, EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
    }
    else
    {
        string value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(guid, EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
        Process process = null;
        int processId = -1;

        if (int.TryParse(value, out processId))
            process = Process.GetProcessById(processId);

        if (process == null || !SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle))
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to start application. An instance of this application is already running.");
    }

    return createdNew;
}
```

Edit: You can also store and initialize mutex and createdNew statically, but you'll need to explicitly dispose/release the mutex once you're done with it. Personally, I prefer keeping the mutex local as it will be automatically disposed of even if the application closes without ever reaching the end of Main.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the same thing implemented via Event.

```
public enum ApplicationSingleInstanceMode
{
    CurrentUserSession,
    AllSessionsOfCurrentUser,
    Pc
}

public class ApplicationSingleInstancePerUser: IDisposable
{
    private readonly EventWaitHandle _event;

    /// <summary>
    /// Shows if the current instance of ghost is the first
    /// </summary>
    public bool FirstInstance { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="applicationName">The application name</param>
    /// <param name="mode">The single mode</param>
    public ApplicationSingleInstancePerUser(string applicationName, ApplicationSingleInstanceMode mode = ApplicationSingleInstanceMode.CurrentUserSession)
    {
        string name;
        if (mode == ApplicationSingleInstanceMode.CurrentUserSession)
            name = $"Local\\{applicationName}";
        else if (mode == ApplicationSingleInstanceMode.AllSessionsOfCurrentUser)
            name = $"Global\\{applicationName}{Environment.UserDomainName}";
        else
            name = $"Global\\{applicationName}";

        try
        {
            bool created;
            _event = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, name, out created);
            FirstInstance = created;
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _event.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I ended up taking care of this issue.  Note that debug code is still in there for testing.  This code is within the OnStartup in the App.xaml.cs file.  (WPF)

```
        // Process already running ? 
        if (Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName).Length > 1)
        {

            // Show your error message
            MessageBox.Show("xxx is already running.  \r\n\r\nIf the original process is hung up you may need to restart your computer, or kill the current xxx process using the task manager.", "xxx is already running!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);

            // This process 
            Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

            // Get all processes running on the local computer.
            Process[] localAll = Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);

            // ID of this process... 
            int temp = currentProcess.Id;
            MessageBox.Show("This Process ID:  " + temp.ToString());

            for (int i = 0; i < localAll.Length; i++)
            {
                // Find the other process 
                if (localAll[i].Id != currentProcess.Id)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Original Process ID (Switching to):  " + localAll[i].Id.ToString());

                    // Switch to it... 
                    SetForegroundWindow(localAll[i].MainWindowHandle);

                }
            }

            Application.Current.Shutdown();

        }
```

This may have issues that I have not caught yet.  If I run into any I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A time saving solution for C# Winforms...

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
// needs reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices;  

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class SingleInstanceController : WindowsFormsApplicationBase
    {
        public SingleInstanceController()
        {
            this.IsSingleInstance = true;
        }

        protected override void OnStartupNextInstance(StartupNextInstanceEventArgs e)
        {
            e.BringToForeground = true;
            base.OnStartupNextInstance(e);
        }

        protected override void OnCreateMainForm()
        {
            this.MainForm = new Form1();
        }
    }

    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
            SingleInstanceController controller = new SingleInstanceController();
            controller.Run(args);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, this is the code I use for single-instance [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) applications:

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main()
{
    String assemblyName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;

    using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, assemblyName))
    {
        if (!mutex.WaitOne(0, false))
        {
            Boolean shownProcess = false;
            Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

            foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName(currentProcess.ProcessName))
            {
                if (!process.Id.Equals(currentProcess.Id) && process.MainModule.FileName.Equals(currentProcess.MainModule.FileName) && !process.MainWindowHandle.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    IntPtr windowHandle = process.MainWindowHandle;

                    if (NativeMethods.IsIconic(windowHandle))
                        NativeMethods.ShowWindow(windowHandle, ShowWindowCommand.Restore);

                    NativeMethods.SetForegroundWindow(windowHandle);

                    shownProcess = true;
                }
            }

            if (!shownProcess)
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "An instance of {0} is already running!", assemblyName), assemblyName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, (MessageBoxOptions)0);
        }
        else
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form());
        }
    }
}
```

Where native components are:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
internal static extern Boolean IsIconic([In] IntPtr windowHandle);

[DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
internal static extern Boolean SetForegroundWindow([In] IntPtr windowHandle);

[DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
internal static extern Boolean ShowWindow([In] IntPtr windowHandle, [In] ShowWindowCommand command);

public enum ShowWindowCommand : int
{
    Hide                   = 0x0,
    ShowNormal             = 0x1,
    ShowMinimized          = 0x2,
    ShowMaximized          = 0x3,
    ShowNormalNotActive    = 0x4,
    Minimize               = 0x6,
    ShowMinimizedNotActive = 0x7,
    ShowCurrentNotActive   = 0x8,
    Restore                = 0x9,
    ShowDefault            = 0xA,
    ForceMinimize          = 0xB
}
```

Comment: The problem by this implementation is that you can't provide any command-line arguments from the second instance back to the first one. For a better explanation [look here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode31SingleInstanceWinFormsAndMicrosoftVisualBasicdll.aspx).

Comment: Doesn't look like the question asks for this. Anyway, this wouldn't be a consistent behavior... an instance being terminated shouldn't modify the behavior of the existing one. If you want your application to behave differently, you close the current process and you start a new one with different parameters.

Comment: But that behaviour is how office works by default. You open the first document by double-click and a new process starts. You open the second document and it will get a window in the first instance.

Comment: I still don't get the point. This wasn't a requested feature.

Comment: It was. The last paragraph of the question is: *The code needs to also inform the already-running instance that the user tried to start a second one, and **maybe also pass any command-line arguments if any existed.***

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [CodeFluent Runtime](http://www.softfluent.com/products/codefluent-runtime-client) which is free set of tools. It provides a [SingleInstance](http://blog.codefluententities.com/2014/09/10/single-instance-application-in-net/) class to implement a single instance application.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnStartup(e As StartupEventArgs)
    Const appName As String = "TestApp"
    Dim createdNew As Boolean
    _mutex = New Mutex(True, appName, createdNew)
    If Not createdNew Then
        'app is already running! Exiting the application
        MessageBox.Show("Application is already running.")
        Application.Current.Shutdown()
    End If
    MyBase.OnStartup(e)
End Sub
```

Comment: I like simple solutions, so I tried this first... could not get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my 2 cents

```
 static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            bool createdNew;
            using (new Mutex(true, "MyApp", out createdNew))
            {
                if (createdNew) {
                    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                    var mainClass = new SynGesturesLogic();
                    Application.ApplicationExit += mainClass.tray_exit;
                    Application.Run();
                }
                else
                {
                    var current = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
                    foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName(current.ProcessName).Where(process => process.Id != current.Id))
                    {
                        NativeMethods.SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is "NativeMethods" class?

Answer (score 0):

I like a solution to allow multiple Instances, if the exe is called from an other path. I modified CharithJ solution Method 1:

```
   static class Program {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern Int32 SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        foreach (var process in Process.GetProcesses()) {
            try {
                if ((process.Id != currentProcess.Id) && 
                    (process.ProcessName == currentProcess.ProcessName) &&
                    (process.MainModule.FileName == currentProcess.MainModule.FileName)) {
                    ShowWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, 5); // const int SW_SHOW = 5; //Activates the window and displays it in its current size and position. 
                    SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);
                    return;
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                //ignore Exception "Access denied "
            }
        }

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply using a `StreamWriter`, how about this?

```
System.IO.File.StreamWriter OpenFlag = null;   //globally
```

and

```
try
{
    OpenFlag = new StreamWriter(Path.GetTempPath() + "OpenedIfRunning");
}
catch (System.IO.IOException) //file in use
{
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the proposed solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59706160/c-sharp-dot-net-core-single-instance-app-passing-parameters-to-first-instance) that uses a semaphore to determine if an existing instance is already running, works for a WPF application and can pass arguments from second instance to the first already running instance by using a TcpListener and a TcpClient:

It works also for .NET Core, not only for .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my entire `App.xaml.cs`, this code also brings the launched program instance to the foreground:

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    private static Mutex _mutex = null;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        _mutex = new Mutex(true, "YourMutexName", out var createdNew);

        if (!createdNew)
        {
            using (var currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            {
                foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName(currentProcess.ProcessName))
                {
                    if (process.Id != currentProcess.Id)
                    {
                        ShowWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, 9);
                        SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);
                    }
                    process.Dispose();
                }
            }
            // app is already running! Exiting the application  
            Shutdown();
        }

        base.OnStartup(e);
    }

    protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        _mutex.Dispose();
        base.OnExit(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My favourite solution is from MVP Daniel Vaughan:
[Enforcing Single Instance Wpf Applications](http://danielvaughan.org/posts/.net/wpf/2010/08/01/Enforcing-Single-Instance-WPF-Applications/)

It use MemoryMappedFile to send command line arguments to the first instance:

```
/// <summary>
/// This class allows restricting the number of executables in execution, to one.
/// </summary>
public sealed class SingletonApplicationEnforcer
{
    readonly Action<IEnumerable<string>> processArgsFunc;
    readonly string applicationId;
    Thread thread;
    string argDelimiter = "_;;_";

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the string that is used to join 
    /// the string array of arguments in memory.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The arg delimeter.</value>
    public string ArgDelimeter
    {
        get
        {
            return argDelimiter;
        }
        set
        {
            argDelimiter = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SingletonApplicationEnforcer"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="processArgsFunc">A handler for processing command line args 
    /// when they are received from another application instance.</param>
    /// <param name="applicationId">The application id used 
    /// for naming the <seealso cref="EventWaitHandle"/>.</param>
    public SingletonApplicationEnforcer(Action<IEnumerable<string>> processArgsFunc, 
        string applicationId = "DisciplesRock")
    {
        if (processArgsFunc == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("processArgsFunc");
        }
        this.processArgsFunc = processArgsFunc;
        this.applicationId = applicationId;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines if this application instance is not the singleton instance.
    /// If this application is not the singleton, then it should exit.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns><c>true</c> if the application should shutdown, 
    /// otherwise <c>false</c>.</returns>
    public bool ShouldApplicationExit()
    {
        bool createdNew;
        string argsWaitHandleName = "ArgsWaitHandle_" + applicationId;
        string memoryFileName = "ArgFile_" + applicationId;

        EventWaitHandle argsWaitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(
            false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, argsWaitHandleName, out createdNew);

        GC.KeepAlive(argsWaitHandle);

        if (createdNew)
        {
            /* This is the main, or singleton application. 
                * A thread is created to service the MemoryMappedFile. 
                * We repeatedly examine this file each time the argsWaitHandle 
                * is Set by a non-singleton application instance. */
            thread = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (MemoryMappedFile file = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen(memoryFileName, 10000))
                        {
                            while (true)
                            {
                                argsWaitHandle.WaitOne();
                                using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = file.CreateViewStream())
                                {
                                    var reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
                                    string args;
                                    try
                                    {
                                        args = reader.ReadString();
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception ex)
                                    {
                                        Debug.WriteLine("Unable to retrieve string. " + ex);
                                        continue;
                                    }
                                    string[] argsSplit = args.Split(new string[] { argDelimiter }, 
                                                                    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                                    processArgsFunc(argsSplit);
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Unable to monitor memory file. " + ex);
                    }
                });

            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            /* Non singleton application instance. 
                * Should exit, after passing command line args to singleton process, 
                * via the MemoryMappedFile. */
            using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting(memoryFileName))
            {
                using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
                {
                    var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
                    string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
                    string joined = string.Join(argDelimiter, args);
                    writer.Write(joined);
                }
            }
            argsWaitHandle.Set();
        }

        return !createdNew;
    }
}
```

Comment: try - using - while - using - try --> -1

Answer (score -1):

Based Matt Davis' answer, wrapped into a class for convenience.

```
public static class SingleAppInstanceChecker
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Arbitrary unique string
    /// </summary>
    private static Mutex _mutex = new Mutex(true, "0d12ad74-026f-40c3-bdae-e178ddee8602");

    public static bool IsNotRunning()
    {
        return _mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true);
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    if (!SingleAppInstanceChecker.IsNotRunning())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Application is already running.");

        // Exit application using:
        // Environment.Exit(1);
        // Application.Current.Shutdown();
        // Etc...

        return;
    }
    
    // Allow startup and continue with normal processing
    // ...
}
```